# regex in find doesn't accept the or operator in group

Tags: macos, bash, regex, find

I'm trying to delete all files and directories in a parent directory, with the exclusion of some directories and their content. For this I use **find** in a bash script on MacOS. It works if I exclude only one directory:

`find ./public/wp-content -mindepth 1 ! -regex '^.\/public\/wp-content\/themes\(.*\)' -delete`

But when I try to exclude multiple it doesn't:

`find ./public/wp-content -mindepth 1 ! -regex '^.\/public\/wp-content\/\(themes\|images\)\(.*\)' -delete`

I tried not to escape the parantheses or the pipe, etc. Nothing works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `-E` option in order to accept Extended Regular Expression:

```
find -E ./public/wp-content -mindepth 1 ! -regex '^\./public/wp-content/\(themes\|images\).*' -delete
```

or:

```
find -E ./public/wp-content -mindepth 1 ! -regex '^\./public/wp-content/(themes|images).*' -delete
```

Comment: I had to reformat it a bit: `find -E ./public/wp-content -mindepth 1 ! -regex '^\./public/wp-content/\(themes\|images\).*'` Then it seems to work. Thank you!

Comment: @Philipp: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: I would expect `\(` in ERE to literally match `(` and unescaped `(` to be special (exactly opposite as in BRE); similarly I would expect `\|` to literally match `|`. In other words I would expect `(themes|images)` to be the right substring. Oh well, maybe `find` in MacOS is different.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: You're may be right, I haven't MacOS to test but OP seems to valid the answer.

Comment: I had a longer answer about BRE vs ERE and the conclusion was `find -E …`; but when you posted yours, I decided to step aside (you can now see it as deleted). The problem of `\(` has bothered me since. And I don't use MacOS either. In my answer I deliberately omitted `-delete` because I wasn't able to test it thoroughly.